# Statement: [infix] will [whole] [suffix] [prefix] [infix] will

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> [infix] will [whole] [suffix] [prefix] [infix] will.

The above, when the gaps are filled, will be a reasonable statement.

What are the two infixes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **HE** will **INHERIT** **IT** **IN** **HER** will.

So the infixes are

> **HE** and then **HER**

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense than my working suggestion of HE will LATHER HER LATHE AT will...!